# Check if directory exists in ~/ using Perl

Tags: perl, directory

I noticed strange behavior of the `-d` flag to check if a file is a directory and if the directory exists. It behaves differently when using `~/my_dir` as my path.

The following code will return false, even though the directory `my_dir` exists, but if I'll change it to a full path like `/home/ricky/my_dir`, then the `if` statement will return true.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#
use strict;

if ( -d "~/my_dir") {
    print "Found \n";
}
else {
    print "Not found \n";
}
```

What's the difference?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976968/why-does-my-perl-script-fail-on-but-works-with-envhome & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043785/how-can-i-make-perl-recognize-paths-with/

Comment: Also try `ls "~/mydir"` - you'll figure the `difference`.

Comment: Thanks, those solutions uses other modules that I'm always trying to avoid, but I got the point :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`~` is a *shell* shortcut to indicate the home directory, it is unknown to perl. You have to use the environment variable `HOME` here -- for instance using `"$ENV{HOME}/my_dir"`.

Comment: BTW, using system vs back-ticks makes ~/ work in the 'system' function, which is also a difference that I just found ... ( also symlinks have the same issue ) - thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Unknown to the *system*, even. Perl doesn't do anything with the path but pass it to the system.

Comment: @Ricky That's because the `system` function runs a `/bin/sh`, which will do its shell substitutions on your command line.

Comment: @aschepler I just run system('echo $SHELL'); and it says /bin/bash .. so I'm not sure this is correct.

Comment: That's just the environment variable.  Try `system(q(ps $$))`.

Comment: @aschepler I'm not sure what I'm suppose to see ... this is the output 17507 pts/0    R+     0:00 ps 17507

Answer (score 5):

`~` is not a real path.  Shells such as `/bin/bash` expand it to the value of the `$HOME` environment variable.  Perl does not.  So, you should use something like this instead:

```
if ( -d "$ENV{HOME}/my_dir" ) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can check by executing the chdir command also.
chdir "dir_name" will return 0, if directory is not present. And 1 if directory is present.

Comment: `-d` is the correct way to tell whether a directory exists. `chdir` has the side effect of changing to the directory; it will also fail if `dir_name` is a directory but you don't have permission to change to it. And this doesn't address the OP's problem, which is the use of `~`.